# sudden multiple errors for one line

Tags: errors

I am in the final stages of reviewing my thesis. When I tried to open the file today the pdf could not be generated. I tried to compile the file but numerous errors appeared on the line containing \begin{document}
Latex file :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt, openright]{book}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%Remove following comment (disabled double space)
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfloat}
%\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{url,hyperref,lineno,microtype,subcaption}
\usepackage{tabulary, makecell}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage[numbers,super]{natbib}

%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{makeidx}  % allows for indexgeneration
% \makeindex          % be prepared for an author index
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.66, 0.66, 0.66}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}

\usepackage{longtable}

%\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
%\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{natbib}


\BeforeBeginEnvironment{figure}{\vskip-2ex}
\AfterEndEnvironment{figure}{\vskip-1ex}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{table}{\vskip-2ex}
\AfterEndEnvironment{table}{\vskip-1ex}





\hypersetup{
    pdftitle=TITLE
    pdfauthor=FirstName LastName,
    pdfsubject=Ph.D. Thesis,
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=black
}
\def\acrobat{\hyperdef{jump}{here}{}}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
%Remove following comment (disabled one half space)
\onehalfspace
%\linespread{1.25}
% for setting the spacing refer to
%http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3907092

\parindent 0mm
\parskip 0.5cm
\newcommand{\degree}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}


\begin{document}
%\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}
\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

{\LARGE{Agile Methodology Implementation in Lebanon}}\\


%\vspace{30mm}
\vspace{55mm}
{\large Scarlet Rahy} \\
\vspace{20mm}
\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{salfordlogo} \\
{{\Large{\textsc{University of Salford }}} \\
\rule[0.1cm]{9.2cm}{0.1mm} \\
\rule[0.5cm]{9.2cm}{0.6mm} \\
{\small{\textsc{School of Computing, Science and Engineering}}}} \\
\vspace{20mm}
\textsc{\today} \\
\vspace{20mm}
\small{This document is toward the degree of Doctor of Philosophy} \\
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}


\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mybib}



\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
%\input{chapter_appendices_a}
\input{chapter_appendices_b}







\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
%\chapter{Publications}
%is this seat taken
%trying to pull up a chair
\end{document}
```

This is the log error i have now

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.96 \begin{document}
                     
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.96 \begin{document}
                     
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Extra \endcsname.
\check@bm@number ...0\else \csname B_#1\endcsname 
                                                  \fi 
l.96 \begin{document}
                     
I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.96 \begin{document}
                     
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

(thesis.out)
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \endgroup 
l.96 \begin{document}
                     
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \endgroup 
l.96 \begin{document}
                     
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Use of \B_ doesn't match its definition.
<recently read> \endgroup 
                          
l.96 \begin{document}
                     
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \endcsname 
l.96 \begin{document}
                     
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \endcsname 
l.96 \begin{document}
                     
A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
(If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)

! Extra \else.
\ReadBookmarks ...fx \WriteBookmarks \relax \else 
                                                  \if@filesw \newwrite \@out...
l.96 \begin{document}
                     
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@outlinefile 
                         
l.96 \begin{document}
                     
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ... \immediate \closeout \@outlinefile 
                                                  \ReFiCh@Check {}\x {\jobna...
l.96 \begin{document}
                     
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \x 
              
l.96 \begin{document}
                     
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...Ch@0 \MessageBreak After: \space \x 
                                                  \@gobble 
l.96 \begin{document}
                     
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\ReadBookmarks ...mmediate \openout \@outlinefile 
                                                  =\jobname .out\relax \ifHy...
l.96 \begin{document}
                     
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Extra \fi.
\ReadBookmarks ... {<relaxxml>\relax }\fi \fi \fi 
                                                  
l.96 \begin{document}
                     
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

! Extra \fi.
\Hy@AtBeginDocumentHook ...per \ReadBookmarks \fi 
                                                  \Hy@pdfstringtrue \PDF@Set...
l.96 \begin{document}
                     
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

)
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 96.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> ./thesis.tex
                
The file ended while I was skipping conditional text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

! Emergency stop.
<*> ./thesis.tex
                
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 15713 strings out of 480930
 247181 string characters out of 2894163
 565272 words of memory out of 3000000
 31248 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 533143 words of font info for 26 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 41i,1n,45p,1124b,1066s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please don't post screenshots: we need code that we can cut and paste, preferably in the form of a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). The problem is not with the `\begin{document}` line, which is of course OK, so it must be in your preamble or in your aux file. From the error messages it may have something to do with floats. Try deleting your aux file and recompiling. If it still fails then please add your entire log file to the question -- not a screen shot but the actual file.

Comment: I deleted the aux file and recompiled but it did not work.

Comment: I added also a minimal working example that reproduces the issue starting with \documentclass and ending with \end{document}

Comment: Unrelated: Why are you missing with space above and below figures and tables like that? When there are buildin settings you can change. See the `memoir` manuals chapter about floats (it explains all the float settings unrelated to the memoir class)

Comment: We cannot test this code as you include files we don't have access to. But since the error comes before `\begin{document}` you should be able to make an example without the input files.

Comment: how can i give you access to these codes. does it help to repost the code with the \input{chapter_...}

Comment: Please provide the actual log file instead of the filtered log file from your editor. That filtering often miss important stuff. Unrelated see the `siunitx` package for proper units like `\degree`

Comment: If you right after `\begin{document}` write `hello world \end{document}` then everything after `\end{document}` is ignored. Does the file then compile? If not, post the log file of that compilation. It compiles just fine for me.

Comment: I tried writing hello word \end{document} but it did not work.

Comment: I am trying to post the log file but it is too long. Any idea how i can send it to you

Comment: `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` is followed by a `\usepackage{natbib}` ... You should use each package once ... I think this is a part of your problem

Comment: we can not run the code you posted as it uses files that we don't have (although you should definitely remove `\BeforeBeginEnvironment{figure}{\vskip-2ex}` and similar as they will have the effect of making paragraphs of text over-print. The figure will float to another page but the negative spacing will stay at that position in the source,  make a small but compete example that shows the problem (you can delete any package not used in the example, which will make the log smaller) no document written this century should be using `epsfig` anyway!

Comment: If I comment out the instruction `\input{chapter_appendices_b}` (since I don't have access to that file) and add the document class option `demo` (since I don't have access to your graphics files), your code compiles without errors on my system (MacOS 10.15.6 "Catalina", MacTeX2020).

Comment: Is it possible that i have a command that is wrong in the body of the text?

Comment: That is not the proper log, Please post the full proper log. There are stuff in the log before this

Comment: yes i know but it does not fit

Comment: Then send it to my gmail, it is just my username @gmail.com